# How to get reponse from ajax on submit button in ASP.NET MVC form in current page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I click on button "Submit", I want to stay on the page and make an Ajax call, and just show success alert box. But with this code it redirects me to

```
http://localhost:65464/Home/TestMethod
```

My HMTL:

```
(...)
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestMethod", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" align="center">Person Details</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>PersonId: </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

My controller:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public bool TestMethod()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

I want to keep this "Razor" syntax, because I have annotations in my model (validations).

I can put in .js file ajax and to call this method, but then I can't validate directly from annotations my model in form. How to stay on the page without redirecting?

Updated js file:

```
 $('#submitBtn').click(function () {
    //var form = $('#emailForm');
    //form.validate();
    var obj = new Object();
    obj.Name = $('#Name').val();
    obj.CheckInCheckOutDate = $('#CheckInCheckOutDate').val();
    obj.MobilePhone = $('#MobilePhone').val();
    obj.EMail = $('#EMail').val();
    obj.AdultsNumber = $('#AdultsNumber').val();
    obj.ChildrenNumber = $('#ChildrenNumber').val();
    obj.MessageBody = $('#MessageBody').val();
    obj.MobilePrefixCountry = $('#MobilePrefixCountry').val();
    obj.ApartmentName = $('#ApartmentName').val();
    obj.NumberOfNights = $('#NumberOfNights').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/SendEmail",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            $('#successAlert').show('fade')
                .delay(3000)
                .fadeOut(function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#errorAlert').show('fade')
                .delay(3000)
                .fadeOut(function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
        },
    });
});
```

I am calling different method but the priciple is the same actually..

What I tried based on @D-Shiha solution:
js:

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('happy');
});
```

my new html:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestMethod", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" align="center">Person Details</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>PersonId: </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Comment: Could you show us you js ajax code?

Answer (score 0):

First assign form id like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestMethod", "Home", FormMethod.Post,new {id="idForm"}))
{...
```

Handle form submit and serialize form and send by ajax operation like this.

```
$("#idForm").submit(function(e) {
    var form = $(this);        
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/Home/SendEmail",
           data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {

           }
         });

    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Do not need all of these

<strike>obj.Name = $('#Name').val();</strike>

<strike>obj.CheckInCheckOutDate = $('#CheckInCheckOutDate').val();</strike>

<strike>obj.MobilePhone = $('#MobilePhone').val();</strike>

<strike>obj.EMail = $('#EMail').val();</strike>

<strike>obj.AdultsNumber = $('#AdultsNumber').val();</strike>

...

Answer (score 0):

You can use AjaxHelper instead of the HTMLHelper to construct the form to submit the page without a full post-back to the server. this will help you validate the form using annotations and control the success and failure callbacks.

The Ajax.BeginForm takes the following parameters

- actionName
- controllerName
- routeValues
- ajaxOptions
- htmlAttributes

first add the reference of jquery.unobtrusive-ajax library from NuGet Packages

[image]

Replace this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestMethod", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
```

with this

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("TestMethod", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST"}))
```

and you can add OnSuccess event to the AjaxOptions with the JS callback function

Hope this helps.

Please refer to this link for more details : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/ajax-beginform-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/

AjaxHelper class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd505113(v=vs.118)